# In Clojure, how can I better design this code that needs to be polymorphic?

Tags: design-patterns, clojure, multimethod

I'm writing this program that is like a web crawler for online forums.  For each forum I crawl, I need to do the same thing:

1. login
2. find the boards
3. find the posts
4. find the permalink to the post
5. find username of the person who made the post
6. etc.

Now while this same logic needs to occur for each forum, the implementation for each forum is different.  For example, the inputs of each login form is different per forum.  One forum may have a field named "username" the other may have a field named "user".  Some of these steps may have default implementations.  For example, the default implementation of `login` is to not do anything (because you don't have to login to some forums to crawl it).

What I've done is created a function with all these steps in it named `crawl-forum` but the implementations are abstract and implemented elsewhere.  My question is, **what's the best way to get `crawl-forum` to use these implementations?**

## What I've tried

#### 1) Config map

Here's what I've tried so far.  I added a new argument to the `crawl-forum` function called `configs`.  It's a map data structure that looks like this:

```
{ :login login-function
  :find-boards find-boards-function
  ...
}
```

The code that calls `crawl-forum` is responsible for populating that map.  What I don't like about this is the `configs` need to be passed throughout the `crawl-forum` code.  It adds a new parameter everywhere.  Also, I've got some lame, ad-hoc code for handling default implementations.

#### 2) Multimethods

I talked on irc about this and someone gave me the idea that I should use multimethods for this instead since it's really polymorphic behavior.  They look like this:

```
(defn get-site-key [& args] (first args))
(defmulti login get-site-key)
(defmethod login :default [site-key cookie-store] nil)
```

Then the client code has to define its own multimethods on the outside:

```
(defmethod login :forum-1 [site-key cookie-store] (do-something cookie-store))
```

What I don't like about this is that just like the `config`, I have to pass the `site-key` in to the `crawl-forum` function and that `site-key` still has to be passed around everywhere inside.  Also, every `defmethod` has to be passed its own `site-key` back as a parameter, but none of them will *ever* use it.  It's simply a necessary argument to do dispatch on.  It's really hard for me to find a thorough multimethod tutorial though, so if there's a smarter way to do this, let me know.

Is there a 3rd option that's even better?  Is there a better way to be using multimethods?  Let me know, thanks.

Comment: Using a config map does not seem like an anti-pattern. Could you use the not-found option of `get`, the `or` macro, and the `:or` directive in destructing to alleviate your "lame, ad-hoc code for handling default implementations"? If using multimethods, you have the default as well.

Comment: @A.Webb That's exactly what I did.  I thought it was kind of lame because the map was passed all around, but the `:or` was defined for each function right before it was used.  Maybe I should have done this all in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option 1. If passing the map around bother you, you can always use a dynamic var. For the defaults, what I would suggest is to use merge:

```
(def defaults { ... })
(def site-specific (merge defaults { ...}))
```

Comment: Nice.  Is there any way around those multimethod issues I was having though?  The `site-key` issues were annoying and I'd like to know if they can be solved for educational purposes.

Comment: You can also solve it with a dynamic var that stores the site :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Protocols`.  These are the successors to multimethods which support polymorphic behavior. In addition, when you define a Protocol, it can compile to a Java interface with the `:gen-class` namespace directive.

Here are some good links to help your understanding:

- [Rifle-Oriented Programming with Clojure](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2009/05/27/rifle-oriented-programming-with-clojure)
- [Polymorphism in Clojure](http://blog.8thlight.com/myles-megyesi/2012/04/26/polymorphism-in-clojure.html)

However, I am partial to a simple implementation approach. Maintain a map of forum URLs to map of your functions, i.e.

```
(def config 
  {"http://forum1.com" {:login login-function1
                          :find-boards find-boards-function1 ... }
   "http://forum2.com" {:login login-function2 
                          :find-boards find-boards-function2 ... }
    ;; etc
   "http://forumN.com" {:login login-functionN
                          :find-boards find-boards-functionN ... }})
```

and elsewhere

```
(crawl-forum (get config forum-url))
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with this simple approach in a small application. Interfaces and polymorphism are for large projects with team members separated by distance and time.

Comment: I think you may be saying this yourself, but I don't see how Protocols would make any aspect of this better.  Also, it doesn't fit with the problem because I don't have a variation of types, just different keyword/url.  Also:

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your suggestion, or you're misunderstanding my question, but I would need multiple functions per forum.  So I'd need a map of maps.  Or maybe you're saying I should copy and paste the `crawl-forum` code each time I have a new forum I want to process?  I don't like that idea for (hopefully) obvious reasons.

Comment: Since you just wrote "copy-paste" your true goal here is DRY code, which implies what you might need is a macro.

Comment: I.e. crawl-forum is actually a macro that takes your map data and emits a function for each forum.